# How do I multiply a matrix by a matrix in C? Why doesn't this work?

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, multiplication

This is the program I'm working on. The task is to multiply 2 matrices. The number of columns in Matrix A are the same as the number of rows in Matrix B. Below is a comment on what the two matrices contain and what the expected result is. The computed result is what my program does.

```
void matrixMul(Matrix A, Matrix B, int ARows, int ACols, int BCols, Matrix C){
int k;
int l;
int j;
    for(j=0; j < ARows; j++) {
        for (l=0; l < BCols; l++) {
            for (k=0; k < ACols; k++) {
                C[j][l] += A[j][k] * B[k][l];
            }/*for*/
        }/*for*/
    }/*for*/
}/*matrixMul*/


/*This is what the output should be....
  ==> Computing 0.0   1.0   2.0      0.0   1.0   2.0
                1.0   2.0   3.0  *   3.0   4.0   5.0
                2.0   3.0   4.0      6.0   7.0   8.0

==> Expected    15.0  18.0  21.0
                24.0  30.0  36.0
                33.0  42.0  51.0

==> Computed    15.0  20.0  25.0
                28.0  36.0  44.0
                41.0  52.0  63.0 */
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. What is the type `Matrix`?  Can you show the code that prints out your two matrices?  Do you set matrix C to zero before you start adding to it?  Please see how to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — two names and links for the same basic idea.

Comment: Inside the middle loop, have you tried to add `c[l][k] = 0`, before the beginning of the innermost loop. What happens then? Moreover, it seems you playing with somethingy other than integers, inside the matrix, please elaborate on that front also.

Comment: @nIcEcOw: I think it will be right to add `C[j][l] = 0;` before the third nested loop.

Answer (score 3):

Your equations look right. I can only guess that `C` not initialized to all zeros before the computation. I would do this (just to be sure):

```
for(j=0; j < ARows; j++) {
    for (l=0; l < BCols; l++) {
        C[j][l] = 0;                      // <- Init C to zero
        for (k=0; k < ACols; k++) {
            C[j][l] += A[j][k] * B[k][l];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code works correctly when the matrix C is zeroed:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef double Matrix[3][3];

static void print_matrix(const char *tag, Matrix M);
static void matrixMul(Matrix A, Matrix B, int ARows, int ACols, int BCols, Matrix C);

void matrixMul(Matrix A, Matrix B, int ARows, int ACols, int BCols, Matrix C)
{
    int k;
    int l;
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < ARows; j++)
    {
        for (l = 0; l < BCols; l++)
        {
            for (k = 0; k < ACols; k++)
            {
                C[j][l] += A[j][k] * B[k][l];
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    Matrix A = { { 0.0, 1.0, 2.0 }, { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 }, { 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 }, };
    Matrix B = { { 0.0, 1.0, 2.0 }, { 3.0, 4.0, 5.0 }, { 6.0, 7.0, 8.0 }, };
    Matrix C = { { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 }, };

    print_matrix("A", A);
    print_matrix("B", B);

    matrixMul(A, B, 3, 3, 3, C);

    print_matrix("C", C);
    return 0;
}

static void print_matrix(const char *tag, Matrix M)
{
    printf("%s:\n", tag);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            printf("%6.2f", M[i][j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Output:

```
A:
  0.00  1.00  2.00
  1.00  2.00  3.00
  2.00  3.00  4.00
B:
  0.00  1.00  2.00
  3.00  4.00  5.00
  6.00  7.00  8.00
C:
 15.00 18.00 21.00
 24.00 30.00 36.00
 33.00 42.00 51.00
```

You can easily fix the code in the multiplication function so that the initial contents of the result matrix do not matter:

```
void matrixMul(Matrix A, Matrix B, int ARows, int ACols, int BCols, Matrix C)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < ARows; j++)
    {
        for (int l = 0; l < BCols; l++)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < ACols; k++)
                sum += A[j][k] * B[k][l];
            C[j][l] = sum;
        }
    }
}
```

There's a decent chance that a good optimizing compiler would produce essentially the same code as in this revision with `C[j][l]` not used inside the innermost loop.